# How to add clicked signal and slot to custom button in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Box class that inherits from `QPushButton`. I want to have a onClick event on the button by using connect (SIGNAL and SLOT) and call a custom function `onClick()` declared in box.h

```cpp
box.h
#ifndef BOX_H
#define BOX_H

#include <QPushButton>

class Box : public QPushButton {
public:
    Box(const QString& text, QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    void onClick();
};

#endif // BOX_H
```

```cpp
//box.cpp
#include "box.h"

Box::Box(const QString& text, QWidget* parent)
    : QPushButton(text, parent)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(this->onClick()));
}

void Box::onClick()
{
    this->setText("Something");
}
```

Comment: `connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(this->onClick()));` - *Please* stop using the old macro / string based signal/slot syntax. Use the new pointer-to-member-function based syntax instead. The new way is compile-time checked rather than run-time checked, is faster and you can connect to anything (so you don't need to mark functions as slots any more). Forget about `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` already.

Comment: `SLOT(this->onClick())` is incorrect. The connection should have failed. Qt should have logged this but if you don't have a console window you may not see that.

Comment: Yes, what is the correct syntax?
it showes ```QObject::connect: No such slot QPushButton::onClick()``` error

Comment: SLOT(onClick())

Comment: `connect(this, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Box::onClick);`

Comment: Is this the new syntax for signal and slots?

Comment: I find myself still using the old syntax because I am still stuck using Qt4 on some existing large projects which have library dependencies that make porting to Qt5 a very time intensive task.

Comment: ***Is this the new syntax for signal and slots?*** Yes this `connect(this, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Box::onClick);` is the Qt5 syntax. One good thing also mentioned in the first comment is if you get it wrong you get a compiler error instead of a log message during runtime.

Comment: Is there a way to make this ```Box``` class into a custom widget so that I can drag and drop it in the ui creator?

Comment: Yes you can do that. https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/adding-plugins.html Although I find it simpler to just use the promote feature of designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your box needs the label for defining slots

```
class Box : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Box(const QString& text, QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    //may be public or private
    public slots:
    
        void onClick();
};
```

Comment: The `Q_OBJECT` macro is only needed if the class contains signals. These days, with the new *member-function-pointer* style `connect`, you don't need special declarations of slots.